# How to set default Date in bootstrap datepicker in Angular 4?

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

I am using Bootstrap Datepicker in Angular 4, I want to set current date as default in Text Box, here is my code:

```js
// COMPONENT CODE
$('#submission_date').datepicker({
  autoclose: false,
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
})
```

HTML code:

```html
<input type="text" formControlName="submission_date" ngModel="{{getAssignment.submission_date | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" id="submission_date">
```

**NOTE: I am using Reactive Form.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NgModel` or `formControlName`.

For  `ngModel` use :

```
const getAssignment.submission_date: NgbDateStruct = { year: 1789, month: 7, day: 14 }; // July, 14 1789
```

Or for `formControlName` use :

```
this.submission_date.setValue({ year: 1789, month: 7, day: 14 });
```